# How to delete record using where 2 conditions (AND) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, controller

When I delete a record, in a controller, laravel deletes the condition one by one. It is not deleting two conditions at once.

Can we delete records for 2 conditions that have been determined, not to delete records for every single condition.

Comment: Please share the query that you are using.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
use App\Models\YourModel;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function deleteRecords()
    {
        // Define your two conditions
        $condition1 = 'your_first_condition';
        $condition2 = 'your_second_condition';

        // Delete records that meet both conditions
        YourModel::where('column1', '=', $condition1)
                 ->where('column2', '=', $condition2)
                 ->delete();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Records deleted successfully']);
    }
}
```